# Trigger with if

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with a trigger on mysql with this code:

```
delimiter //
create trigger myimage_trigger before insert on products
for each row
begin
   if (NEW.image is null ) then
      set NEW.image = 'link image';
   end if;
end
//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: ...so what's the problem? Also, what does Angular have to do with this? In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it adds a little **context** to help clarify your **intent**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve the problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: if the image field is null I insert a link to an image, but all this is after the product field is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend having the table column `image` containing a default value and when inserting use `insert into table1 values (5, DEFAULT)` where you have an image value you want to have the default value.